# How to set bot's custom status with Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've just gotten started with Discord.py, and I would like to set a custom status for it, i.e. "Watching for e/info" but am not sure how to do that. Only thing found on SO was for Discord.js.

My code:

```
import os
import random
from dotenv import load_dotenv

from discord.ext import commands

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='e/')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await  bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity 
    (type=discord.ActivityType.watching name="for e/info"))

@bot.command(name='info')
async def info(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Prefix: /e) Commands: \n    -info => Shows commands')


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

(I followed a tutorial for this minus the Status thing, I think I'm missing an `import` statement, I'm just not sure what to `import`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `.change_presence()` method. Assuming you're using `discord.Client()`

```
await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='Watching for e/info'))
```

Also there's different kinds of statuses, Playing, Watching, Listening, and Streaming. So if you wanted it to use Watching, do this instead.

```
await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="for e/info"))
```

Comment: Would this work with `Bot`? I know that `Bot` is a subclass of `Client`..

Comment: You should just be able to replace `client` with `bot`.

Comment: can i remove the `await`

Comment: it says await can't be used outside of a function, so when I remove await it says that discord is undefined @duckboycool

Comment: You have to put this in an event for it to work. If you want it to do it on the bot's startup, then just put it in the `on_ready` with something like this script here. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#a-minimal-bot

Comment: switched it to `bot.change_presence` and this happened:
`await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="for e/info"))
NameError: name 'discord' is not defined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213730/discussion-between-eaglegaming-and-duckboycool).